# Elastic Search Bool Query for multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I have index mapping like follows:

Request

```
|-> tilte 
|-> countryCode
|-> isOpen
|-> location
|-> date
```

I want to make bool and geoquery at the same time fetching the docs that within the same country and near me also which `isOpen` I have tried the below but always I am getting an empty hits object.

```
{   "from" : 5,
    "size": 5,
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {"match" : {"countryCode": "US"}},
                {"match": {"isOpen": true }}
            ],
            "filter" : {
                "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "150km",
                    "location" : {
                        "lat" : 1111111111,
                        "lon" : 3333333333
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    "sort": [ { "date" : {"order" : "desc"} } ]
 }
```

**The response**

```
{
    "took": 8,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

even though I am sure that there are many documents matches the query but I can't get it. Any one can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with changing `from` value from 5 to 0. Nextly I would check index definition - are you sure each of the field can be searched in a way you're using it? Can you show exact index definiton (mapping) and show sample item from Elastic?